# Can not use jwt.sign,res.headers is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

Following code is giving me error (res.headers is not a function) for jwt.sign
Any suggestions?
Is it because of syntax?

```
 app.post('/logIn', async (req, res) => {
 //Checking if email exists
 const user = await User.findOne({username:req.body.username})
 if (!user) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Username')
 //Password is correct
 const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password,user.password)
 if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Invalid password')

 //Create and assign a token

 const token = jwt.sign({user},'secretkey')
 res.headers('auth-token',token).send(token)

 // res.send('Logged in ')


})
```

Comment: what's the error? tip you don't want to pass all of user else will include password and other useless info, only need an id

Comment: I'm getting unhandled promise error

Comment: on what line? also if you're using async/await you should use try/catch

Comment: I checked once again and it said res.headers is not a function

Comment: remove the `s` its `res.header(..`

Comment: Bruh,I always make simple errors like that,thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is **jwt** here? Did you define it?

```
var jwt = require('express-jwt');

app.use(jwt({
  secret: 'hello world !'
}));

const token = jwt.sign({user})
```

Also you can define secret before signing tokens.

Comment: Yes I did define it

Comment: You can define secret before signing tokens. Can you design code like that?

Comment: I will try one moment

Comment: The error which popped up was res.headers is not a function

Comment: res.cookie('jwt',token, { maxAge: 3600000 }) You should actually set a cookie not a header.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to use `res.header` instead of `res.headers` ?